# Directory forbidden centos7

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, centos7, codeigniter-3

Hi I've been searching the solution over 2 days so don't say it duplicate.. I really couldn't find the answer.. xd

I'm trying to build LAMP server on Amazon-EC2(Centos7). This will be copy of my existing web server(and it is centos6). 
When I finished installing httpd, php I created index.php in /var/www/html/ it worked well. Then I tried to unzip Codeigniter3 folder and moved them into /var/www/html/ it worked well too showing Codeigniter's welcome page.

Next I copied my running webserver's(cent6) html/ to here cent7's /var/www/html using git clone. From here it shows 'Directory access is forbidden.' though I set entire html/ to 777. I tried inserting 'allow from all'things from another answers and replaceing httpd.conf file too, still doesn't work. I also tried restorecon -r html.

The html/ from my runnign webserver has almost the same structure with Codeigniter3's unzipped folder..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to [disable the SELinux](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/02/27/how-to-disable-selinux-in-red-hat-or-centos/)